# how to correctly resolve a promise in nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
const findusers=(commentarr)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        let final_comment_arr=[];
        commentarr.forEach(element=>{
            comment.findOne({_id:element}).then(result_comment=>{
                final_comment_arr.push(result_comment);
            });
        })
        resolve(final_comment_arr);
        reject(new Error('failed to find users'));
    })
}
```

when i resolve with the array it returns an empty array how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you use mongodb, there is a `$in` to find all IDs in that array instead of looping through.

```
const findusers=(commentarr)=>{
    return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
       let result = await comment.find({ _id: { $in: commentarr }})
       if(result.length < 1){
          reject(new Error('failed to find users'));
       }else {
          resolve(result);
       }
    })
}
```

I am not sure if `result` returns an array or just `null`. Maybe you console log it to check it out

Comment: @omarsayed try to work with the mongodb operators, its faster and more efficient: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Answer (score 0):

So your `comment.findOne` is an asynchrous call. You could debug it to see an order of asynchrouns calls. What I mean is you have a rica condition and probably `resolve(final_comment_arr);` is called before any of `comment.findOne` is resolved. You could change your solution to sth like:

```
    const findusers=(commentarr)=>{
         return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
             let commentsPromises = commentarr.map(element=> comment.findOne({_id:element}))
             resolve(Promise.all(commentsPromises)) // resolve is like a return for Promie
    })
}
```

Promise.all is a function that takes array of promises and return result when each of them resolves

(Note: I didn't run this code, so there might some syntax errors)

To make resolving example easier I removed this error handling

You could simlify my example to:

```
    const findusers=(commentarr)=>
         Promise.all(commentarr.map(element=> comment.findOne({_id:element})))
```